# How to use HBase?

Tags: hbase

I need help regarding database. I am trying to create a Java project which uses the data from 25 different XML files to display a graph. My question is can the Hbase be used such that I can pass the key value pair from the database to my Java code? How should I install Hbase in my code? I have tried various methods, such as installing Cygwin and SSH, but the SSH service does not start.
I want to use Hbase with eclipse. I have even tried installing the Hbase eclipse plug in but that is of no use too. Can some one please help me out? Is there any easier way to use Hbase? I just want to implement the Hbase mapping functionality in my code. Please help me out.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use HBase? Are your XML files in GBs?

Comment: I agree that your question is ill-defined.  You need to explain what your problem is and why HBase is the correct solution.  Also; HBase is difficult to run on Windows.  MS is trying to make it easier, but I would look for a different NoSQL solution if you are restricted to Windows

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you haven't configured the ssh daemon correctly.
bear in mind that there's a lot of steps to get this working:

http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/User:Fkorning/Code/Hadoop-on-Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

HBase 0.95 actually can actually run on Windows without Cygwin. It ships with a start-hbase.cmd which you can run straight from windows, and which will launch HBase on stand-alone mode.

That said, I really do not understand what you are trying to achieve with HBase. What do you mean by "implement the Hbase mapping functionality in my code"?

Really unless your data volumes are on the TB range, your access patterns relatively simple, and your volumes of read/writes very high it really does not apply...